# codeigniter custome validation for multiple input controls together

Tags: codeigniter, custom-validators

In my **codeigniter** form contains year , month selectboxes and many input controls. how to validate selected year and month already exitsts in my mysql table when form submitting ? ( custom validation for multiple input controls togethers)

Answer (score 0):

ur question is not clear.

but i think you need  to verify if a selected year and month by user is already exist or not. if that's it  ur question you need to create ajax request with jquery to verify they are exist or not

Comment: am new to codeigniter, but i have littile bit idea of form validation in codeigniter.there we use set_rules() for each controls to be validated.my question is how to check values of year and month combination already in table using set_rules()?